# LinkedIn historical company statistics giving me the wrong number of followers

Tags: linkedin-api

I am attempting to write a backfill script that will pull in historical follower numbers for linkedin companies we are missing data for. My current script is able to get data back from linkedin, but these numbers appear incorrect for my test company. I am using this company: https://www.linkedin.com/company/3802814

I make a historical follower statistics call like so: 
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/3802814/historical-follow-statistics?start-timestamp=315554400&end-timestamp=1421349947&time-granularity=day&format=json

(these timestamps correspond to 01/01/1980 and 01/15/2015)

The data I'm getting back indicates 14 (not 6, as my company actually has) followers, all on random/incorrect dates, with all 0s:

`{
    "_total": 14,
    "values": [
        {
            "organicFollowerCount": 0,
            "paidFollowerCount": 0,
            "time": 259200000,
            "totalFollowerCount": 0
        },
        {
            "organicFollowerCount": 0,
            "paidFollowerCount": 0,
            "time": 345600000,
            "totalFollowerCount": 0
        },
        ... (10 more similar records)
        {
            "organicFollowerCount": 0,
            "paidFollowerCount": 0,
            "time": 1296000000,
            "totalFollowerCount": 0
        },
        {
            "organicFollowerCount": 0,
            "paidFollowerCount": 0,
            "time": 1382400000,
            "totalFollowerCount": 0
        }
    ]
}`

I would have guessed my timestamps were wrong until I saw that it's giving me more followers than I should actually have. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Looking at the linkedin docs has thus far not given me any obvious answers. Data I expect would be a series of daily records updated by # of followers added on a given day. These followers were primarily added sometime in December 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the proper request you should be making to get the information you are looking for:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/3802814/historical-follow-statistics?start-timestamp=315561600000&time-granularity=day&end-timestamp=1421308800000&format=json
```

You want to make sure you are using the timestamps in milliseconds.

The total value you are also seeing is the # of results - not the # of followers.